# Why class active not working on the second loop?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, laravel-5.3

My code is like this :

```
<div class="row no-gutter">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <h2 class="nav-cat-text">By Players</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9 col-xs-12">
        <div class="wrap-tabs">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-cat">
                @foreach($categories as $category)
                    @if($category->parent_id == 1)
                    <li role="presentation" class="{{ $loop->first ? 'active' : '' }}"><a href="javascript:;" data-toggle="tab">{{ ucfirst($category->name) }}</a></li>
                    @endif
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<br>
<!-- By Types -->
<div class="row no-gutter">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <h2 class="nav-cat-text">By Types</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9 col-xs-12">
        <div class="wrap-tabs">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-cat">
                @foreach($categories as $category)
                    @if($category->parent_id == 2)
                    <li role="presentation" class="{{ $loop->first ? 'active' : '' }}"><a href="javascript:;" data-toggle="tab">{{ ucfirst($category->name) }}</a></li>
                    @endif
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

By players and by types, each has five tabs

When the code is executed, the first tab on by players is active

But why the first tab on by types is not active?

Comment: you  mean to say categories are the tabs in your code??

Comment: @Sona, Yes, categories are the tabs

Answer (score 0):

Its look like you make mistake in if condition look in first loop you use this condition

```
 @if($category->parent_id == 1)
```

and in second one you use this

```
 @if($category->parent_id == 2)
```

so in `By Types` first is not active

Answer (score 0):

The main problem here that your first item has `parent_id = 1` and so it's the first loop so it's active.
but in the second foreach the first item hasn't `parent_id = 2` because it of course has `parent_id = 1` as mentioned before.

#### Solution:

before every @foreach. `<?php $x= 0;?>`
and edit code to be like that:

```
@if($category->parent_id == 1)
    <li role="presentation" class="{{ $x == 0 ? 'active' : '' }}">
      <a href="javascript:;" data-toggle="tab">
           {{ ucfirst($category->name) }}
      </a>
    </li>
    <?php $x =1 ?>;
@endif
```

and the same for second loop

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use collections from laravel.

First you can separate your categories using filter function like the following.

```
<?php

$players = collect($categories)->filter(function($value){
    return $value->parent_id === 1;
});

$types = collect($categories)->filter(function($value){
    return $value->parent_id === 2;
});
?>
```

Now, that you have separate categories, loop them.

```
@foreach($players as $category)
    <li role="presentation" class="{{ $loop->first ? 'active' : '' }}">
        <a href="javascript:;" data-toggle="tab">{{ ucfirst($category->name) }}</a>
    </li>
@endforeach

@foreach($types as $category)
    <li role="presentation" class="{{ $loop->first ? 'active' : '' }}">
        <a href="javascript:;" data-toggle="tab">{{ ucfirst($category->name) }}</a>
    </li>
@endforeach
```